# Are $\mathrm{Pin}(3, 1)$ and $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, semi-riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

In physics, it’s very common to utilize the group (exceptional) isomorphism
$$
  \mathrm{Spin}^{+}(1, 3) \approx \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})
$$
in problem solving. I’m working with $\mathrm{Pin}$ groups instead and was wondering if the above generalizes to the isomorphism:
$$
  \mathrm{Pin}^{+}(1, 3) \approx \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \,?
$$

I haven’t been able to find it anywhere, I would think it’s as simple as dividing each $M \in \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ by it’s determinant via a map
$$
  M \rightarrow M' = \det(M)^{-n} M \in \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \,.
$$
I don’t know very much about $\mathrm{Pin}$ groups however, and not sure if that would work on the left-hand side.
Can anyone show if this does (or doesn’t) work?

Comment: Pin and Spin have the same dimension, unlike SL and GL. Maybe if you take the semidirect product of SL with complex conjugation you get an isomorphic copy of Pin?

Comment: @runway44  Thank you, I was unaware. One never hears about a reduction of the frame bundle through the Pin group to the Spin group, so that makes sense.

Comment: Note that for an invertible $(n × n)$-matrix $M$, the matrix $M / \det(M)$ won’t have determinant $1$ but $1 / \det(M)^{n - 1}$ (since the determinant is multilinear in columns/rows, and thus $\det(λM) = λ^n \det(M)$ for every scalar $λ$).

Comment: @JendrikStelzner  Thank you, that was sloppy of me.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to show $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$. The answer is they are not isomorphic as the mapping $M \rightarrow M/\sqrt{\det(M)}$ is not injective since $M$ and $M/\sqrt{\det(M)}$ is mapped to same matrix inside $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. But as @runway44 pointed out in the comments there is problem in making this map a homomorphism due to the fact that square root is not unique but we can have the following isomorphism: Let $K = \{ cI \mid c \in \mathbb{C}, c \neq 0 \}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. We have that $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}) /  \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \cong K$. This can be done using the map $M \rightarrow \det(M)$.

Please define the $\mathrm{Pin}$ group in the question so that I can make my answer better.

Comment: Is $M\mapsto M/\sqrt{\det M}$ even well-defined? Supposing you choose a branch-cut for the square root, it is then well-defined but is neither continuous nor a homomorphism,

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for pointing out. You are correct. I edited my answer. Let me know if you still think the answer needs correction.

Comment: @Balajisb I definitely was *NOT* asking if $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are isomorphic as the are clearly different Lie groups. Thank you for the answer, Still not all that familiar with pin groups either.

Comment: @R.Rankin Why did you accept this answer if it is does not answer your question...?

Comment: @Pedro  whoops, that was an accident, I found the answer useful and meant to +1 it